# Android storage of drawable images in res folders gives error

Tags: android

So im trying to save an image in one of the drawable folders in my android problem but no matter where i put the image file, trying to build or run my program gives this error

```
C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:621: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:657: null returned: 1
```

the offending lines of code are:

```
621-elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java">
657-proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
```

As soon as i remove the image file my application cleans and builds and runs with no problems. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: SLCC-map.png someone just told me it may be the upper letters, gotta try that

Comment: u can use only a-z or 1-9 or _ or .(dot)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upper case letters are not allowed in resource file names. Did you verify?

Comment: hmmmm i did not know that, lemme try renaming it